# Changing app stores

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 4S and I changed to the US store to view an app not available in the SA store. Now I cannot change back to the SA store. The message comes up that I need to change with no directions on how to do this.
How can I change stores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1311?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_USmay) would be a place to start.

In the Settings app:

- tap Store in the sidebar
- tap your Apple ID on the right
- tap View Apple ID
- enter password if required
- tap Country/Region

You will need a valid payment method on file for the country you're changing to, which I assume you already have.

Comment: Changing store and changing AppleID country are two different things.

Comment: Yes they are. The question didn't ask how to change AppleID country though.

Comment: Isn't your answer about how to change AppleID country?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that changing stores and changing AppleID country are two distinct things.

If you changed stores just to **look at** another App, but didn't actually change your AppleID country to buy something in this new store, then you can revert to your original store by just trying to upgrade an App that you had installed from this original store. You should then be asked if you want to change stores again. This is the behaviour with IOS 11 at least.

You can switch stores to just look at Apps available there, but you'll not be able to install or purchase anything from it unless you also convert your AppleID account.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an app to change the App Store Country with just a click.

Here you can find the app: https://www.producthunt.com/posts/app-store-country-changer-aso-hack

I only need to switch the country for my ASO strategy.